# if file exist does not find the file ending with .php

Tags: php

I need to check if a file exist but the system cannot find the file, it may be because the code is ending the $var with .php I dont know. Here is the code

```
  $thefile=$_POST['files'];
    if (file_exists('/infrastructure/datacenter/'.$thefile.'.php'))
{include('infrastructure/datacenter/'.$thefile.'.php');}
```

Any idea why the file cannot be found? Because the file really exist

the file name in the test is 2001.php and it does exist but php says it does not exist

SOLVED

There was a missing / in the include second path

Comment: anything from http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ? you may have to update your post to include the HTML/form for this.

Comment: you start one of the file paths with `/` and the other without, that have anything to do with it?

Comment: well what's the actual name of the file on disk. How can you "not know" whether it's because the code is appending ".php" to it. Does the file you want to find end with ".php"? What's the contents of "$thefile"? Why do you start one of your paths with "/" but not the other? BTW allowing a postback to control what PHP files get executed strikes me as a massive security disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Yeah the file name in the test is 2001.php and it does exist but php says it does not exist

Comment: Is the file in the same directory as the file that contains this code?

Comment: Yeah I will try this with the /in path

Comment: yes its in the same directory thats why I am sure it exist

Comment: It was the path / as WheatBeak said

Comment: you should be very very careful doing what you are doing, if you slip up you can expose other files on your system or even let php include a remote file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the if statement checking an absolute path, while your include statement is relative.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

There was a missing / in the include second path